# wtpdmt - Windows thread preemption duration measurement tool (C++)

Tags: console, windows, c++20, winapi, exercise

I have [this repository](https://github.com/coderodde/wtpdmt). The idea is that the user may measure for how long the thread is preempted with given priority class/thread priority.

**`CommandLineParser.h:`**

```
#define COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_WTPDMT_UTIL_COMMAND_LINE_PARSER_HPP

#include <filesystem>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <windows.h>

namespace com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util {

    using std::string;

    class CommandLineParser {
    private:

        bool m_iteration_flag_present;
        bool m_priority_class_flag_present;
        bool m_thread_priority_flag_present;
        bool m_help_flag_present;

        char** m_argv;
        int m_argc;
        int m_argument_index;

        size_t m_iterations;
        DWORD m_priority_class;
        int m_thread_priority;

        std::unordered_map<string, std::function<void(CommandLineParser&)>> m_flag_processor_map;
        std::map<string, DWORD>    m_priority_class_name_map;
        std::map<string, int>      m_thread_priority_name_map;
        std::unordered_set<DWORD>  m_priority_class_number_set;
        std::unordered_set<int>    m_thread_priority_number_set;
        std::unordered_set<string> m_flag_set;

    public:
    
        CommandLineParser(int argc, char* argv[]);

        size_t getNumberOfIterations();
        DWORD getPriorityClass();
        int getThreadPriority();
        bool helpRequested();
        void printHelp();
        string getPriorityClassName(DWORD priority_class);
        string getThreadPriorityName(int thread_priority);
        size_t getMaximumPriorityClassNameLength();
        size_t getMaximumThreadPriorityNameLength();

    private:
    
        void loadDispatchMap();
        void loadPriorityClassNameMap();
        void loadThreadPriorityNameMap();
        void loadPriorityClassNumberSet();
        void loadThreadPriorityNumberSet();
        void loadFlagSet();
        void parseCommandLine();
        void checkFlagIsValid(string& flag);
        void checkMoreParametersAvailable();
        void processFlagPair();
        void processHelpFlags();
        void processIterationFlags();
        void processPriorityClassFlags();
        void processThreadPriorityFlags();
        template<class T>
        void parseValue(string& value, T* target_ptr);
    };
} // End of namespace com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util
#endif // COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_WTPDMT_UTIL_COMMAND_LINE_PARSER_HPP
```

**`CommandLineParser.cpp:`**

```
#include "CommandLineParser.h"'
#include <filesystem>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <windows.h>

using std::string;

static const string HEXADECIMAL_REGEX_PATTERN = "0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})";
static const std::regex HEXADECIMAL_REGEX = std::regex(HEXADECIMAL_REGEX_PATTERN);

static const string DECIMAL_REGEX_PATTERN = "-?([0-9]{1,10})";
static const std::regex DECIMAL_REGEX = std::regex(DECIMAL_REGEX_PATTERN);

static bool IsHexadecimalString(string& str) {
    return std::regex_match(str, HEXADECIMAL_REGEX);
}

static bool IsDecimalString(string& str) {
    return std::regex_match(str, DECIMAL_REGEX);
}

// Priority class names:
static const string ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR   = "ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS";   // 0x00008000
static const string BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR   = "BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS";   // 0x00004000
static const string HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR           = "HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS";           // 0x00000080
static const string IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR           = "IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS";           // 0x00000040
static const string NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR         = "NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS";         // 0x00000020
static const string PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN_STR = "PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN"; // 0x00100000
static const string PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END_STR   = "PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END";   // 0x00200000
static const string REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR       = "REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS";       // 0x00000100

// Thread priority names:
static string THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN_STR  = "THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN";  // 0x0010000
static string THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END_STR    = "THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END";    // 0x00020000
static string THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL_STR  = "THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL";  // 1
static string THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL_STR  = "THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL";  // -1
static string THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST_STR       = "THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST";       // 2
static string THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE_STR          = "THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE";          // -15
static string THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST_STR        = "THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST";        // -2
static string THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL_STR        = "THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL";        // 0
static string THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL_STR = "THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL"; // 15

// Program flags:
static string FLAG_LONG_HELP                 = "--help";
static string FLAG_LONG_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS = "--iterations";
static string FLAG_LONG_PRIORITY_CLASS       = "--priority-class";
static string FLAG_LONG_THREAD_PRIORITY      = "--thread-priority";

static string FLAG_SHORT_HELP                 = "-h";
static string FLAG_SHORT_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS = "-i";
static string FLAG_SHORT_PRIORITY_CLASS       = "-p";
static string FLAG_SHORT_THREAD_PRIORITY      = "-t";

static const size_t DEFAULT_M_ITERATIONS      = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
static const DWORD  DEFAULT_M_PRIORITY_CLASS  = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
static const int    DEFAULT_M_THREAD_PRIORITY = THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL;

com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::CommandLineParser(int argc, char* argv[]) :
    m_iteration_flag_present      { false },
    m_priority_class_flag_present { false },
    m_thread_priority_flag_present{ false },
    m_help_flag_present           { false },
    m_argv                        { argv },
    m_argc                        { argc },
    m_argument_index              { 1 },
    m_iterations     { DEFAULT_M_ITERATIONS },
    m_priority_class { DEFAULT_M_PRIORITY_CLASS },
    m_thread_priority{ DEFAULT_M_THREAD_PRIORITY }
{
    loadDispatchMap();
    loadPriorityClassNameMap();
    loadThreadPriorityNameMap();
    loadPriorityClassNumberSet();
    loadThreadPriorityNumberSet();
    loadFlagSet();
    parseCommandLine();
}

size_t com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::getNumberOfIterations() {
    return m_iterations;
}

DWORD com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::getPriorityClass() {
    return m_priority_class;
}

int com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::getThreadPriority() {
    return m_thread_priority;
}

bool com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::helpRequested() {
    return m_help_flag_present;
}

template<class Value>
size_t getMapStringKeyMaximumLength(std::map<string, Value>& map) {
    size_t maximum_string_length = 0;

    for (const auto& i : map) {
        maximum_string_length = max(maximum_string_length,
                                    i.first.length());
    }

    return maximum_string_length;
}

size_t com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::getMaximumPriorityClassNameLength() {
    return getMapStringKeyMaximumLength(m_priority_class_name_map);
}

size_t com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::getMaximumThreadPriorityNameLength() {
    return getMapStringKeyMaximumLength(m_thread_priority_name_map);
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::printHelp() {
    size_t maximum_class_name_length = getMapStringKeyMaximumLength(m_priority_class_name_map);
    size_t maximum_thread_priority_name_length = getMapStringKeyMaximumLength(m_thread_priority_name_map);

    string programFileName = std::filesystem::path(m_argv[0]).filename().string();

    std::cout << programFileName
              << " "
              << "[" << FLAG_SHORT_PRIORITY_CLASS       << "|" << FLAG_LONG_PRIORITY_CLASS       << " <CLASS>] "
              << "[" << FLAG_SHORT_THREAD_PRIORITY      << "|" << FLAG_LONG_THREAD_PRIORITY      << " <THREAD>] "
              << "[" << FLAG_SHORT_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS << "|" << FLAG_LONG_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS << " <ITERATIONS>] "
              << "[" << FLAG_SHORT_HELP                 << "|" << FLAG_LONG_HELP                 << "]\n"
              << "where:\n\n"
              << "  <CLASS> is one of: \n";

    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill(' ');

    for (auto& i : m_priority_class_name_map) {
        std::cout
            << "    "
            << std::setw(maximum_class_name_length)
            << std::left
            << std::setfill(' ')
            << i.first
            << " -- Sets the process class to 0x"
            << std::hex
            << std::right
            << std::setfill('0')
            << std::setw(8)
            << i.second
            << " = "
            << std::dec
            << i.second
            << (i.second == DEFAULT_M_PRIORITY_CLASS ? " (default)" : "")
            << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\n  <THREAD> is one of:\n";

    for (auto& i : m_thread_priority_name_map) {
        std::cout
            << "    "
            << std::setw(maximum_thread_priority_name_length)
            << std::left
            << std::setfill(' ')
            << i.first
            << " -- Sets the thread priority to 0x"
            << std::hex
            << std::right
            << std::setfill('0')
            << std::setw(8)
            << i.second
            << " = "
            << std::dec
            << i.second
            << (i.second == DEFAULT_M_THREAD_PRIORITY ? " (default)" : "")
            << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}

string com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::getPriorityClassName(DWORD priority_class) {
    for (const auto& p : m_priority_class_name_map) {
        if (p.second == priority_class) {
            return p.first;
        }
    }

    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << "Unknown priority class: 0x"
       << std::setw(8)
       << std::right
       << std::setfill('0')
       << std::hex
       << priority_class
       << " = "
       << std::dec
       << priority_class
       << ".";

    throw std::logic_error{ ss.str() };
}

string com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::getThreadPriorityName(int thread_priority) {
    for (const auto& p : m_thread_priority_name_map) {
        if (p.second == thread_priority) {
            return p.first;
        }
    }

    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << "Unknown thread priority: 0x"
       << std::hex
       << thread_priority
       << " = "
       << std::dec
       << thread_priority
       << ".";

    throw std::logic_error{ ss.str() };
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::loadDispatchMap() {
    std::function<void(CommandLineParser&)> function_flag_iterations = &CommandLineParser::processIterationFlags;

    m_flag_processor_map[FLAG_LONG_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS]  = function_flag_iterations;
    m_flag_processor_map[FLAG_SHORT_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS] = function_flag_iterations;

    std::function<void(CommandLineParser&)> function_flag_priority_class = &CommandLineParser::processPriorityClassFlags;

    m_flag_processor_map[FLAG_LONG_PRIORITY_CLASS]  = function_flag_priority_class;
    m_flag_processor_map[FLAG_SHORT_PRIORITY_CLASS] = function_flag_priority_class;

    std::function<void(CommandLineParser&)> function_flag_thread_priority = &CommandLineParser::processThreadPriorityFlags;

    m_flag_processor_map[FLAG_LONG_THREAD_PRIORITY]  = function_flag_thread_priority;
    m_flag_processor_map[FLAG_SHORT_THREAD_PRIORITY] = function_flag_thread_priority;

    std::function<void(CommandLineParser&)> function_flag_help = &CommandLineParser::processHelpFlags;

    m_flag_processor_map[FLAG_LONG_HELP]  = function_flag_help;
    m_flag_processor_map[FLAG_SHORT_HELP] = function_flag_help;
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::loadPriorityClassNameMap() {
    m_priority_class_name_map[ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR]   = ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
    m_priority_class_name_map[BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR]   = BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
    m_priority_class_name_map[HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR]           = HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS;
    m_priority_class_name_map[IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR]           = IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS;
    m_priority_class_name_map[NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR]         = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
    m_priority_class_name_map[PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN_STR] = PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN;
    m_priority_class_name_map[PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END_STR]   = PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END;
    m_priority_class_name_map[REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS_STR]       = REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS;
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::loadThreadPriorityNameMap() {
    m_thread_priority_name_map[THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN_STR]  = THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN;
    m_thread_priority_name_map[THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END_STR]    = THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END;
    m_thread_priority_name_map[THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL_STR]  = THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL;
    m_thread_priority_name_map[THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL_STR]  = THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL;
    m_thread_priority_name_map[THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST_STR]       = THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST;
    m_thread_priority_name_map[THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE_STR]          = THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE;
    m_thread_priority_name_map[THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST_STR]        = THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST;
    m_thread_priority_name_map[THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL_STR]        = THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL;
    m_thread_priority_name_map[THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL_STR] = THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL;
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::loadPriorityClassNumberSet() {
    for (const auto& p : m_priority_class_name_map) {
        m_priority_class_number_set.emplace(p.second);
    }
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::loadThreadPriorityNumberSet() {
    for (const auto& p : m_thread_priority_name_map) {
        m_thread_priority_number_set.emplace(p.second);
    }
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::parseCommandLine() {
    while (m_argument_index < m_argc) {
        processFlagPair();

        if (m_help_flag_present) {
            return;
        }
    }
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::loadFlagSet() {
    m_flag_set.emplace(FLAG_LONG_HELP);
    m_flag_set.emplace(FLAG_LONG_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    m_flag_set.emplace(FLAG_LONG_THREAD_PRIORITY);
    m_flag_set.emplace(FLAG_LONG_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS);

    m_flag_set.emplace(FLAG_SHORT_HELP);
    m_flag_set.emplace(FLAG_SHORT_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    m_flag_set.emplace(FLAG_SHORT_THREAD_PRIORITY);
    m_flag_set.emplace(FLAG_SHORT_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS);
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::checkFlagIsValid(string& flag) {
    if (!m_flag_set.contains(flag)) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Unknown flag: " << m_argv[m_argument_index] << ".";
        throw std::logic_error{ ss.str() };
    }
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::checkMoreParametersAvailable() {
    if (m_argument_index == m_argc) {
        // Once here, the last flag has no value:
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "No value for the flag '" << m_argv[m_argc - 1] << ".";
        throw std::logic_error{ ss.str() };
    }
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::processFlagPair() {
    string flag = m_argv[m_argument_index];

    if (flag == FLAG_LONG_HELP || flag == FLAG_SHORT_HELP) {
        m_help_flag_present = true;
        return;
    }

    // First check that the currently indexed flag is correct:
    checkFlagIsValid(flag);

    // Check that there is more parameters in the command line:
    m_argument_index++;
    checkMoreParametersAvailable();

    // Process the flag:
    (m_flag_processor_map[flag])(*this);
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::processHelpFlags() {
    m_help_flag_present = true;
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::processIterationFlags() {
    if (m_iteration_flag_present) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "The flag "
            << FLAG_SHORT_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS
            << " or "
            << FLAG_LONG_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS
            << " given more than once.";

        throw std::logic_error{ ss.str() };
    }

    m_iteration_flag_present = true;
    string value = m_argv[m_argument_index];
    std::istringstream ss(value);
    ss >> m_iterations;
    m_argument_index++;
}

template<class T>
void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::parseValue(string& value, T* target_ptr) {
    if (IsHexadecimalString(value)) {
        // Try parse as hexadecimal:
        std::istringstream iss(value);
        iss >> std::hex >> *target_ptr;

        if (iss.fail() || iss.bad()) {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "Could not parse '"
               << value
               << "' as a valid hexadecimal value.";

            throw std::logic_error{ ss.str() };
        }
    } else if (IsDecimalString(value)) {    
        // Try parse as decimal:
        std::istringstream iss(value);
        iss >> *target_ptr;

        if (iss.fail() || iss.bad()) {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "Could not parse '"
               << value
               << "' as a valid decimal value.";

            throw std::logic_error{ ss.str() };
        }
    } else {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Could not parse '"
           << value
           << "' as a hexadecimal or decimal value.";

        throw std::logic_error{ ss.str() };
    }
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::processPriorityClassFlags() {
    if (m_priority_class_flag_present) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "The flag "
            << FLAG_SHORT_PRIORITY_CLASS
            << " or "
            << FLAG_LONG_PRIORITY_CLASS
            << " given more than once.";

        throw std::logic_error{ ss.str() };
    }

    auto pair = m_priority_class_name_map.find(m_argv[m_argument_index]);

    if (pair == m_priority_class_name_map.cend()) {
        string value = m_argv[m_argument_index];
        parseValue(value, &m_priority_class);
    } else {
        m_priority_class = pair->second;
    }

    m_priority_class_flag_present = true;
    m_argument_index++;
}

void com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser::processThreadPriorityFlags() {
    if (m_thread_priority_flag_present) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "The flag "
            << FLAG_SHORT_THREAD_PRIORITY
            << " or "
            << FLAG_LONG_THREAD_PRIORITY
            << " given more than once.";

        throw std::logic_error{ ss.str() };
    }

    auto pair = m_thread_priority_name_map.find(m_argv[m_argument_index]);

    if (pair == m_thread_priority_name_map.cend()) {
        string value = m_argv[m_argument_index];
        parseValue(value, &m_thread_priority);
    } else {
        m_thread_priority = pair->second;
    }

    m_thread_priority_flag_present = true;
    m_argument_index++;
}
```

**`main.cpp:`**

```
#include "CommandLineParser.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using std::string;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) try {
    com::github::coderodde::wtpdmt::util::CommandLineParser clp(argc, argv);

    if (clp.helpRequested()) {
        clp.printHelp();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    string priority_class_name  = clp.getPriorityClassName(clp.getPriorityClass());
    string thread_priority_name = clp.getThreadPriorityName(clp.getThreadPriority());

    size_t field_length = max(priority_class_name.length(), 
                              thread_priority_name.length());
    
    std::cout << "Number of iterations:      " 
              << clp.getNumberOfIterations()
              << "\n";

    std::cout << "Requested priority class:  "  
              << std::setw(field_length)
              << std::left 
              << std::setfill(' ')
              << priority_class_name
              << " (0x" 
              << std::setw(8)
              << std::right
              << std::setfill('0')
              << std::hex
              << clp.getPriorityClass()
              << " = "
              << std::dec
              << clp.getPriorityClass()
              << ")\n";

    std::cout << "Requested thread priority: " 
              << std::setw(field_length) 
              << std::left
              << std::setfill(' ')
              << thread_priority_name
              << " (0x"
              << std::setw(8)
              << std::right
              << std::setfill('0')
              << std::hex
              << clp.getThreadPriority() 
              << " = "
              << std::dec
              << clp.getThreadPriority()
              << ")\n\n";

    HANDLE process_handle = GetCurrentProcess();
    HANDLE thread_handle  = GetCurrentThread();

    SetPriorityClass(process_handle, clp.getPriorityClass());
    SetThreadPriority(thread_handle, clp.getThreadPriority());

    std::cout << "INFO: Effective process class is   " 
              << clp.getPriorityClassName(GetPriorityClass(process_handle))
              << ".\n";

    std::cout << "INFO: Effective thread priority is "
              << clp.getThreadPriorityName(GetThreadPriority(thread_handle))
              << ".\n\n";

    ULONGLONG ta = GetTickCount64();
    ULONGLONG maximumDuration = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < clp.getNumberOfIterations(); i++) {
        ULONGLONG tb = GetTickCount64();
        ULONGLONG duration = tb - ta;
        maximumDuration = max(maximumDuration, duration);
        ta = tb;
    }

    std::cout << "INFO: Maximum sleep duration: " << maximumDuration << "\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} catch (std::logic_error& err) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << err.what() << "\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**Help**

```
wtpdmt.exe [-p|--priority-class <CLASS>] [-t|--thread-priority <THREAD>] [-i|--iterations <ITERATIONS>] [-h|--help]
where:

  <CLASS> is one of:
    ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS   -- Sets the process class to 0x00008000 = 32768
    BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS   -- Sets the process class to 0x00004000 = 16384
    HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS           -- Sets the process class to 0x00000080 = 128
    IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS           -- Sets the process class to 0x00000040 = 64
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS         -- Sets the process class to 0x00000020 = 32
    PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN -- Sets the process class to 0x00100000 = 1048576
    PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END   -- Sets the process class to 0x00200000 = 2097152
    REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS       -- Sets the process class to 0x00000100 = 256

  <THREAD> is one of:
    THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN  -- Sets the thread priority to 0x00010000 = 65536
    THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END    -- Sets the thread priority to 0x00020000 = 131072
    THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL  -- Sets the thread priority to 0x00000001 = 1
    THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL  -- Sets the thread priority to 0xffffffff = -1
    THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST       -- Sets the thread priority to 0x00000002 = 2
    THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE          -- Sets the thread priority to 0xfffffff1 = -15
    THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST        -- Sets the thread priority to 0xfffffffe = -2
    THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL        -- Sets the thread priority to 0x00000000 = 0
    THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL -- Sets the thread priority to 0x0000000f = 15
```

**Critique request**
As always, I would like to hear anything about how to improve my C++ routine.

Answer (score 1):

`GetTickCount64` is not great, the result is in milliseconds which is already not amazing but the actual resolution is about 10x worse than that. If the actual preemption duration was consistently, say, 5 milliseconds (which I'm not saying that it would be, just *if*) then you couldn't determine that with `GetTickCount64`, you would end up with a significant overestimation. So, it may be better to use a timing mechanism with a higher resolution.

Taking the maximum of some time deltas is sneaky way to do this, but you may like to know that the ETW API offers context switches as events, so you can actually *directly* get information about them. There is a built-in `NewThreadWaitTime` field too, apparently measured in the mysterious unit of "timer ticks". Don't ask me for details, I never use ETW and the documentation is frankly horrible. But it exists, it seems to be an option, you could look into it.